# tkinter binding to "<Shift_L>" not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to bind a function called `cancel_select()` to the release of the left shift-key.
To do this I use the following line of code:

`self.bind("<KeyRelease-Shift_L>", self.cancel_select)`

Even if I try it without the `KeyRelease-` it does nothing. I think it has something to do with the `Shift_L`, but I have no clue what's wrong with that. I don't get any errors, but it just doesn't do anything. All of my other binds work and the `cancel_select()` works fine too. I can call it with other binds without problems.

**Example**

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame

global i

i = 0
colors = ["red", "green", "blue"]

def change_color(self):
    global i
    if i == 3:
        i = 0
    test_frame.configure(bg=colors[i])
    i += 1

root = Tk()

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

test_frame = Frame(root, bg="#333", width=300, height=300) 
test_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

test_frame.bind("<Button-1>", change_color) # works
test_frame.bind("<Shift_L>", change_color) # doesn't work
test_frame.bind("Shift_L", change_color) # doesn't work

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide a short script that we can test with

Comment: @Mike67 I added an example. I also found out that it doesn't work with any keybinding. Could it be a focus problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems to be a problem of focus. The event is not detected by the frame, unless it has the focus.

`"<Button-1>"` <strike>works because it sets the focus on to the frame.</strike> **Edit:** the button works because it is not a key and thus doesn't require keyboard focus. Thanks @Bryan Oakley for correction.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame

i = 0
colors = ["red", "green", "blue"]

def change_color(self):
    global i
    test_frame.focus_set()
    if i == 3:
        i = 0
    test_frame.configure(bg=colors[i])
    i += 1

root = Tk()

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

test_frame = Frame(root, bg="#333", width=300, height=300) 
test_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

test_frame.bind("<Button-1>", change_color) # works
test_frame.bind("<Shift_L>", change_color) # doesn't work
test_frame.focus_set()

root.mainloop()
```

This seems to work as you expect, because it uses `.focus_set()` method to bring the focus on to the frame. You can refer to [this](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm) and [this](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) for more information on the same.

Comment: This statement is false: _""<Button-1>" works because it sets the focus on to the frame."_ - the button works because it is not a key and thus doesn't require keyboard focus.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with the frame was it never had focus, so it did not receive key events. To allow it to receive key events, set the focus using `focus_set()`

Here is the updated code:

```
test_frame = Frame(root, bg="#333", width=300, height=300) 
test_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

test_frame.focus_set()  # add this line to accept key events

test_frame.bind("<Button-1>", change_color) # works
#test_frame.bind("<Key>", change_color) # works :)
test_frame.bind("<Shift_L>", change_color) # works :)
```

As you mentioned, binding events to the root also works since that captures events for the entire application.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I had to bind the `<Shift_L>` to the root instead of the `test_frame`.

`root.bind("<KeyRelease-Shift_L>", change_color)` worked.